# In XPath, how to test if an expression evaluates to an empty sequence or true()?

Tags: xpath-2.0

If I have an expression such as:

```
node[. << $stop]
```

But I want it to evaluate to true if `.` comes before `$stop` or if `$stop` is the empty sequence.

The challenge is `. << $stop` returns the empty sequence if `$stop` is an empty sequence, resulting in an effective boolean value of false.

For now I have

```
node[if ($stop) then . << $stop else true()]
```

Is there a better or more standard way to perform this type of test?

Comment: perhaps `not(. << $stop eq false())` is an alternative. if `. << $stop` is true the expression is true.  if `. << $stop` is false the expression is false.  if `. << $stop` is an empty sequence, then the expression is true